# How to binning data based on frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Here's what my data

```
id   data
1      89
2      54
3      45
4      67
5      78
6      80
```

Here's the type of output I want

```
Interval    Count
45 - 54         2
67 - 78         2
80 - 89         2
```

I want the data is distributed more evenly

Comment: What is the relevancy of the intervals? Are they just pulled from the data? If you had 7 entries, what would happen?

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge I'm just looking is there any existing pandas function for this, basically I have 100+ of numerical feature and I want to count the PSI (Population Stability Index), and this is just first step

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas` has a function called `qcut()` that would do what you want. Just pass in the `data` column:

```
In []:
qc = pd.qcut(df['data'], q=3, precision=0)
qc

Out[]:
0    (79.0, 89.0]
1    (44.0, 63.0]
2    (44.0, 63.0]
3    (63.0, 79.0]
4    (63.0, 79.0]
5    (79.0, 89.0]
Name: data, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(44.0, 63.0] < (63.0, 79.0] < (79.0, 89.0]]
```

You can use `qc.value_counts()` to get the counts:

```
In []:
qc.value_counts().sort_index()

Out[]:
(44.0, 63.0]    2
(63.0, 79.0]    2
(79.0, 89.0]    2
Name: data, dtype: int64
```